# Get data from array depend on database integer

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model of Posts with status column. I wonder, what would be be practice in Laravel to retrieve from something like 0 or 1(stored integers in DB)  and instead of that show "displayed" or "hidden"? Not inside of the blade temples but when doing something like:

```
        return response()->json(['posts' => $posts])
```

"status" of $posts would be not "0" but "displayed"?

Comment: you could use an accessor, but then every call to `$post->status` would return those strings, you could use a transformer/api resource to transform that field to what you want ... there are ways depends what you want

Comment: Accessors? Yeah it seems what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in **Posts Model**:

```
const displayed  = 1;
const hidden     = 0;
public static function status()
    {
        return [
            self::displayed  => 'displayed',
            self::hidden     => 'hidden',
        ];
    }
```

And retrieve it.

```
$post = [
"status" => Posts::status()[$request->status]
];
```